# What is the best database for full text search?

Tags: full-text-search, lamp

What is the best database for doing a fulltext search?
Lucene and Sphinx are not an option, since the data in my case changes very frequently.
Record count should be 250k+ entries, mostly product descriptions and similar.
LAMP stack.

Comment: If you're looking for a non-MySQL database, then you are not using a LAMP stack.

Comment: It'a LAMP stack, but I plan to export the data, that I like to search, from MySQL into another database which enables me to do a much faster search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you open-source databases.

If you are serious about FTS in the long term and it is a very core feature of your product or application, I would suggest looking at **Solr**. If you are looking to implement simple FTS as a bolt-on to an existing PostgreSQL database, **PostgreSQL** FTS is a fantastic way to do this. PostgreSQL supports UTF8 and multiple languages for spelling, parsing, and stemming. MySQL only supports FTS on MyISAM tables and is really not very good for anything but the most very basic FTS implementation.

Source is [here](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-open-source-database-for-full-text-search-in-many-different-languages)

Comment: Solr looks quite powerful, I'll try it out. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I've looked more into Solr, but I cannot find an answer to one question. Is it possible to organize documents in some sort of sections/databases? For example, my webshop will have 5 stores, each store is separated. So I would like to build one index for each store since I will never do a search on all stores.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/). Its built with document and scalable search in mind. It uses map-reduce technique for its operations. But its not RDBMS. So do some research around couchDB, its open source and fits nicely into LAMP stack.

Comment: CouchDB is a really poor choice for FTS. map/reduce is not FTS and shouldn't even be considered to be used as one.